Recovery my old account
Is anyone able to help with recovering an old Stellar account? I have an address, secret key and recovery token.
Web site(https://launch.stellar.org/#/dashboard) doesn't work.

You are in the same situation as me. The link to upgrade doesn't work, and the old account holders have been abandoned.
